# Using the Tube function to create a torus from an equation for the curve

Tags: plotting, geometry, homework

I've been searching for an answer for this for a while now, but I can't find anything that deals with using the Tube function to generate a torus from the equation of the torus.

The equation of my torus is `z^2==1 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 3`
I want to use `Tube` and `Graphics3D` to show this torus.
I would have thought that

```
Tube[z^2==1 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 3, 1]
```

the second argument being the radius of the tube, would suffice, but I when I evaluate this in `Graphics3D`:

```
 Graphics3D[Tube[z^2 == 1 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 3)^2, 1]]
```

I get the following error:

> Coordinate False should be a triple of numbers, or a Scaled form.

Why? What am I doing incorrectly here? Thanks!

Comment: Appropriate username!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the torus using `Graphics3D` and `Tube`:

```
Graphics3D[Tube[Table[3 {Cos[p], Sin[p], 0}, {p, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/30}], 1],
  Axes -> True]
```

[image: torus]

Comment: Ah, the need to parametrise was what I was missing. Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
Graphics3D[
 Tube[
  BSplineCurve[
   {{-3/2, 0, 1/2}, {-3/2, -3/2, 1/2}, {0, -3/2, 1/2},
    {3/2, -3/2, 1/2}, {3/2, 0, 1/2}, {3/2, 3/2, 1/2},
    {0, 3/2, 1/2}, {-3/2, 3/2, 1/2}, {-3/2, 0, 1/2}},
   SplineDegree -> 2, 
   SplineWeights -> {1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1,  1/Sqrt[2], 1}, 
   SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4}], 
  1/2]
 ]
```

[image]

Adapted from an example in the docs for `Tube`:

```
PieChart3D[{1}, ChartElementFunction -> "TorusSector3D", 
 SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

Comment: For those interested, there is a `BSplineSurface`-based torus on site in [this answer by @J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/170040/4999).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `Tube` as a styling directive with `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[3 {Cos[p], Sin[p], 0}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Tube[1], PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.15]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
ImplicitRegion[
  z^2 == 1 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 3)^2, {x, y, z}] // Region
```

```
ContourPlot3D[
 z^2 == 1 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 3)^2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 
  4}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a much easier way to do it.
My question relates to an exercise in my Mathematica course whereby I have to use Graphics3D and Tube in conjunction to achieve the required shape. Any ideas on this? Thanks